# If statement only runs half way through script

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why can I not run two of these functions at the same time? Someone must have had the same problem I am having. What I am trying to accomplish is for fields that autocomplete (or prefill) because of other fields I want to remove the error validation once there is something in those boxes.

**For example:**

You have a form with a mailing address , a check box marking physical the same as mailing, and the physical address fields. Before anything is filled out the user hits submit, this makes all required fields have a red css box around them. You type in the mailing address the red box disappears. You then hit the check box and it prefills the physical address but does not remove the red box until you click in it. I want as soon as something is filled into the fields the red box disappears regardless if it was prefilled or not. If this makes any sense to anyone please comment.

```
$(document).on('change blur keyup mouseup ', function() {
        if ($('#locality1').val() !== '') {
            $('#locality1').valid();
        }
        if ($('#administrative_area_level_11').val() !== '') {
            $('#administrative_area_level_11').valid();
        }
        if ($('#postal_code1').val() !== '') {
            $('#postal_code1').valid();
        }
        if ($('#auto2complete1').val() !== '') {
            $('#auto2complete1').valid();
        }
        if ($('#locality21').val() !== '') {
            $('#locality21').valid();
        }
        if ($('#administrative_area_level_121').val() !== '') {
            $('#administrative_area_level_121').valid();
        }
        if ($('#postal_code21').val() !== '') {
            $('#postal_code21').valid();
        }
        if ($('#clocality1').val() !== '') {
            $('#clocality1').valid();
        }
        if ($('#cadministrative_area_level_11').val() !== '') {
            $('#cadministrative_area_level_11').valid();
        }
        if ($('#cpostal_code1').val() !== '') {
            $('#cpostal_code1').valid();
        }
        if ($('#locality2').val() !== '') {
            $('#locality2').valid();
        }
        if ($('#administrative_area_level_12').val() !== '') {
            $('#administrative_area_level_12').valid();
        }
        if ($('#postal_code2').val() !== '') {
            $('#postal_code2').valid();
        }
        if ($('#auto2complete2').val() !== '') {
            $('#auto2complete2').valid();
        }
        if ($('#locality22').val() !== '') {
            $('#locality22').valid();
        }
        if ($('#administrative_area_level_122').val() !== '') {
            $('#administrative_area_level_122').valid();
        }
        if ($('#postal_code22').val() !== '') {
            $('#postal_code22').valid();
        }
        if ($('#locality3').val() !== '') {
            $('#locality3').valid();
        }
        if ($('#administrative_area_level_13').val() !== '') {
            $('#administrative_area_level_13').valid();
        }
        if ($('#postal_code3').val() !== '') {
            $('#postal_code3').valid();
        }
        if ($('#auto2complete3').val() !== '') {
            $('#auto2complete3').valid();
        }
        if ($('#locality23').val() !== '') {
            $('#locality23').valid();
        }
        if ($('#administrative_area_level_123').val() !== '') {
            $('#administrative_area_level_123').valid();
        }
        if ($('#postal_code23').val() !== '') {
            $('#postal_code23').valid();
        }
        if ($('#locality4').val() !== '') {
            $('#locality4').valid();
        }
        if ($('#administrative_area_level_14').val() !== '') {
            $('#administrative_area_level_14').valid();
        }
        if ($('#postal_code4').val() !== '') {
            $('#postal_code4').valid();
        }
        if ($('#auto2complete4').val() !== '') {
            $('#auto2complete4').valid();
        }
        if ($('#locality24').val() !== '') {
            $('#locality24').valid();
        }
        if ($('#administrative_area_level_124').val() !== '') {
            $('#administrative_area_level_124').valid();
        }
        if ($('#postal_code24').val() !== '') {
            $('#postal_code24').valid();
        }
        if ($('#locality5').val() !== '') {
            $('#locality5').valid();
        }
        if ($('#administrative_area_level_15').val() !== '') {
            $('#administrative_area_level_15').valid();
        }
        if ($('#postal_code5').val() !== '') {
            $('#postal_code5').valid();
        }
        if ($('#auto2complete5').val() !== '') {
            $('#auto2complete5').valid();
        }
        if ($('#locality25').val() !== '') {
            $('#locality25').valid();
        }
        if ($('#administrative_area_level_125').val() !== '') {
            $('#administrative_area_level_125').valid();
        }
        if ($('#postal_code25').val() !== '') {
            $('#postal_code25').valid();
        }


    });

    $(document).on('change blur keyup mouseup ', function() {
        if ($('#blocality1').val() !== '') {
            $('#blocality1').valid();
        }
        if ($('#badministrative_area_level_11').val() !== '') {
            $('#badministrative_area_level_11').valid();
        }
        if ($('#bpostal_code1').val() !== '') {
            $('#bpostal_code1').valid();
        }
        if ($('#bauto2complete1').val() !== '') {
            $('#bauto2complete1').valid();
        }
        if ($('#blocality21').val() !== '') {
            $('#blocality21').valid();
        }
        if ($('#badministrative_area_level_121').val() !== '') {
            $('#badministrative_area_level_121').valid();
        }
        if ($('#bpostal_code21').val() !== '') {
            $('#bpostal_code21').valid();
        }
        if ($('#clocality1').val() !== '') {
            $('#clocality1').valid();
        }
        if ($('#cadministrative_area_level_11').val() !== '') {
            $('#cadministrative_area_level_11').valid();
        }
        if ($('#cpostal_code1').val() !== '') {
            $('#cpostal_code1').valid();
        }
        if ($('#blocality2').val() !== '') {
            $('#blocality2').valid();
        }
        if ($('#badministrative_area_level_12').val() !== '') {
            $('#badministrative_area_level_12').valid();
        }
        if ($('#bpostal_code2').val() !== '') {
            $('#bpostal_code2').valid();
        }
        if ($('#bauto2complete2').val() !== '') {
            $('#bauto2complete2').valid();
        }
        if ($('#blocality22').val() !== '') {
            $('#blocality22').valid();
        }
        if ($('#badministrative_area_level_122').val() !== '') {
            $('#badministrative_area_level_122').valid();
        }
        if ($('#bpostal_code22').val() !== '') {
            $('#bpostal_code22').valid();
        }
        if ($('#blocality3').val() !== '') {
            $('#blocality3').valid();
        }
        if ($('#badministrative_area_level_13').val() !== '') {
            $('#badministrative_area_level_13').valid();
        }
        if ($('#bpostal_code3').val() !== '') {
            $('#bpostal_code3').valid();
        }
        if ($('#bauto2complete3').val() !== '') {
            $('#bauto2complete3').valid();
        }
        if ($('#blocality23').val() !== '') {
            $('#blocality23').valid();
        }
        if ($('#badministrative_area_level_123').val() !== '') {
            $('#badministrative_area_level_123').valid();
        }
        if ($('#bpostal_code23').val() !== '') {
            $('#bpostal_code23').valid();
        }
        if ($('#blocality4').val() !== '') {
            $('#blocality4').valid();
        }
        if ($('#badministrative_area_level_14').val() !== '') {
            $('#badministrative_area_level_14').valid();
        }
        if ($('#bpostal_code4').val() !== '') {
            $('#bpostal_code4').valid();
        }
        if ($('#bauto2complete4').val() !== '') {
            $('#bauto2complete4').valid();
        }
        if ($('#blocality24').val() !== '') {
            $('#blocality24').valid();
        }
        if ($('#badministrative_area_level_124').val() !== '') {
            $('#badministrative_area_level_124').valid();
        }
        if ($('#bpostal_code24').val() !== '') {
            $('#bpostal_code24').valid();
        }
        if ($('#blocality5').val() !== '') {
            $('#blocality5').valid();
        }
        if ($('#badministrative_area_level_15').val() !== '') {
            $('#badministrative_area_level_15').valid();
        }
        if ($('#bpostal_code5').val() !== '') {
            $('#bpostal_code5').valid();
        }
        if ($('#bauto2complete5').val() !== '') {
            $('#bauto2complete5').valid();
        }
        if ($('#blocality25').val() !== '') {
            $('#blocality25').valid();
        }
        if ($('#badministrative_area_level_125').val() !== '') {
            $('#badministrative_area_level_125').valid();
        }
        if ($('#bpostal_code25').val() !== '') {
            $('#bpostal_code25').valid();
        }


    });
```

I also tried combining them and adding the bottom half with the top but it only runs the top portion of the script. If I switch it and do start the bottom half first then only that portion works. Can someone please enlighten me what is causing this? I thought with if statements it will run all the way down the list and not stop halfway through.

Comment: You could optimize your code a little by giving all fields the same class: `$('.field').each(function() { if ($(this).val()) $(this).valid() })`.

Comment: You could trim that whole thing down to 5 lines of code and avoid the ifs altogether.

Comment: So much copy and pasting! Use a validation library or HTML5 validation.

Comment: Elements can have more than one class.

Comment: What happens when the user changes it back to being empty? Do you invalidate it?

Comment: Add common class like this `<input class="field form-control" id="bauto2complete5">`. And then use the code from my first comment.

Answer (score 2):

All of that code could be reduced to just

```js
$(document).on('change blur', "input", function() {
    var isValid = this.value.length>0;
    $(this).valid(isValid);
});

/* Just to make example run */
jQuery.fn.extend({
  valid: function(isValid) { 
    return this.each(function() {
      var color = isValid ? "lime" : "pink";
      $(this).css("background-color", color);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```

Problem is user can go back and change the text and it would be invalid.

Comment: I would better use `:input` to also cover textareas, selectboxes, etc.

Comment: `if (this.value.length) { /* valid code */ } else { /* invalid code here */ }`

Comment: errrr Iv tried all that and still not doing what I am trying can I explain what I am trying to do?

Comment: @Vicki, the code above is really clean and nicely-written, but you need to be aware that by using the code above, it will apply this "length" validation on **every single input** field on the page where this script is loaded. *You may or may not want that, so be aware of this.*

Comment: isn't that what I have above for jquery?